# read-only cells in ipython/jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to mark a cell in the ipython/jupyter notebook readonly using the json format in the ipynb file? (E.g., a cell attribute `"readonly":false` or some such.) If not, is there a jquery hack to find suppress the double click event in the cell?

Comment: There is currently no such feature [2125](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2125) and [3469](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3469) You could probably do something with the CodeMirror since it supports read only edit fields...

Answer (score 27):

**@Richard Ackon's** answer requires adjustments for JupyterLab:

1. Open the Property Inspector.
2. Focus the cell you want to lock.
3. Add the following lines to the Cell Metadata:

   ```json
   {
       "trusted": true,
       "editable": false,
       "deletable": false
   }
   ```
4. Click on the tick to save the metadata... Tadah!, your cell can't be modified or deleted.

The Property Inspector comes built-in  since JupyterLab 2.0 (note it was moved to the right sidebar by default in JupyterLab 3.0). For older JupyterLab versions you would need to modify the notebook file manually.

[image]

Unfortunately, the outputs can still be cleared by intentionally selecting that option in the menu bar (`Edit` > `Clear Ouputs`). Of course that can only happen if you **DO WANT** to clear the outputs and not just update them by running the cell.

[Source](https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc/issues/2641)

Comment: I tried this but i don't see the tick mark after modifying the cell metadata. I can only see the undo option. Probably some permission relation restriction?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, Use the steps below:

1. Select view on the menubar
2. Point to Cell Toolbar and select Edit Metadata
3. An "Edit Metadata" button will appear at the top-right corner of the cell.
4. Click on that button and edit the json that pops up. Set the editable key to `true` or `false` to get the desired effect.

The JSON will look something like this:

```
{
  "deletable": false,
  "editable": false,
  "scrolled": true,
  "trusted": true
}
```

Comment: There is no key. Only some dictionary like reference.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension for IPython that is supposed to that:

[Read Only Cell extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Readonly).

Getting it to work is something else, but it is there.

Comment: It sounds like you've tried to get it to work. If so, could you post advice here?