# Read Only Python Notebook in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How can we edit an existing .ipynb in Jupyter Lab to be read-only?
More specifically, how can we make specific cells within an existing .ipynb become read-only?

Basically, other users would be able to edit cells that I allow them to (i.e. a cell that specifies an input data file) but all code in other analysis cells can be run but not edited.

If I can't edit an existing .ipynb file to do this, I don't mind saving a notebook with a different name via "Save as" if that makes things easier.

Comment: Please try to do this task and then post your question with code and errors.

Comment: I have found this post from a couple of years ago with a similar question, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18162970

Comment: @Sachith I can't do this feature which is why I'm asking. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: @Matthias I can choose to go back to notebooks instead of jupyter lab and then follow the steps mentioned in that post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read-only cells in ipython/jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162970/read-only-cells-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @krassowski thanks for reaching out! 
I ended up figuring it out since this is an old question.

I appreciate you sending this! :)

Answer (score 3):

**I received an answer (below the underline) from the issue I opened on the JupyterLab GitHub**

Thanks to [Alex](https://github.com/Alexboiboi) for the answer.

Original GitHub Issue post is [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7540).

---

You just need to add

```
{
    "editable": false
}
```

in your cell Metadata.

If you are using Jupyterlab, you can install the [Celltags extension](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-celltags) for ease of metadata editing.