# How to block pasting into jupyter notebook cells?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I want to create a Jupyter notebook with code cells where pasting is blocked (only typing allowed). Everything will be deployed on Jupyter Hub.

I would appreciate any tips on how to achieve it.

Many thanks, Andy

Comment: This sounds like an environment that would be very annoying to use ;) You can make cells [non-editable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977033/6646912) but I think that you would need to write a custom extension to block pasting. It is possible - you would need to add custom event listeners on CodeMirror editor like [discussed here](https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/block-pasting-any-content-inside-the-textarea-or-code-box-area/489) but again, I think this might be a bad idea. If you can explain what is your end goal (is it for students?) I might be able to suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Precisely: it is for students :) I want to follow Zed's Show idea from "learn python  the hard way" - typing everything by hand helped me a lot in my Python learning, so I wanted to create such an env for my DataScience students. At the end of the day, my notebooks would have non editable cells and cells, where only typing is allowed.